# optimize .click( some function ) jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many function

```
//function 1
alert('error_1');

//function 2
alert('error_2');
```

And so on

i need functions run , when I click on buttons  .
For example

```
$('.button_1').click(function() {

     //function 1
     alert('error_1');
     //function 2
     alert('error_2');
     //And so on ...

});

$('.button_2').click(function() {

     //function 1
     alert('error_1');
     //function 2
     alert('error_2');
     //And so on ...

});

$('.button_3').click(function() {

     //function 1
     alert('error_1');
     //function 2
     alert('error_2');
     //And so on ...

});
// And so on
```

but I need optimize this code ,
For example

```
var function_1 = function() {alert('error_1');}
var function_2 = function() {alert('error_2');}
var function_3 = function() {alert('error_3');}
// And so on

$('.button_1').click( function_1 , function_2 , function_3)
$('.button_2').click( function_1 , function_2 , function_3)
$('.button_3').click( function_1 , function_2 , function_3)
// And so on
```

but `.click( function_1 , function_2 , function_3)` doesn't work

So what would u guys suggest me to do ?

Comment: It does not work since that is not valid jQuery.

Comment: On click of any button, you want to execute all three f1,f2,f3 functions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a function that calls all the methods and bind to it.

```
var function_1 = function() {alert('error_1');}
var function_2 = function() {alert('error_2');}
var function_3 = function() {alert('error_3');}
// And so on

$('.button_1, .button_2, .button_3').on("click", function() { 
    function_1();
    function_2();
    function_3();
});
```

And you can simplify the `'.button_1, .button_2, .button_3'` by giving them all a common class.

Answer (score 1):

Once you define the functions, `function_1, function_2, function_3, ....` and you give all your buttons a common class, say `.button`, use this:

```
$('.button').click( function() {
    function_1();
    function_2();
    function_3();
    ....
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use eval:

```
$('.button_1').click(function () {
eval('function_1')();eval('function_2')();eval('function_3')()})
```